# How can I divide the column in a Pivot table by another column in the same PIVOT table in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

[image: Data]

I have tried inserting calculated field, but it only gives a count value or a sum.

I want to calculate the Average Transaction value which is (Total Sales/No of bills)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Does it have to be in the pivot table? You can in the cell right of the pivot table add a formula just like normal `=D2/E2` change columns and rows to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this should work with a calculated field as you described, provided you already got the no. of bills (this could either be a `Count` or a `Sum` Field, depending on your input data) and the amount of total sales in your PT.

The Pic below is in German Excel 2010, however, this should still give you a pretty good idea on how to reporoduce the field

[image]

Comment: I have checked "Add this data to data model", in the insert pivot option to enable unique counting of certain values.
I'm making a Billing and stock management workbook. I cannot insert calculated field.